# Nelson-Aalen estimator for recurrent events

Tags: survival, cox-model, recurrent-events

Can one modify the Nelson-Aalen estimator to use for processes with recurrent events, i.e. when more than one identical events are possible for each subject, with known times of the events?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that Nelson-Aalen estimator *is* the estimator for recurrent events. More precisely: the estimator, initially developed by Nelson for survival analysis, was adapted to recurrent events by Aalen.

My answer relies on [this document](http://www.medicine.mcgill.ca/epidemiology/hanley/c609/Material/NelsonAalenEstimator.pdf).